# MVC: Which method should be overridden to cache action result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm preparing to Microsoft Certificate exam (70-515), reading Microsoft book for this exam, practicing tests... one tests asks:

> You are creating a custom MVC action filter to cache action results.
>
> Which virtual method should you override?

Correct answer (according to test program, that is distributed with a book) is "OnResultExecuting"

And explanation for the answer:

> When you create a custom action filter by inheriting from the ActionFilterAttribute class, you can override four virtual methods that run in the following order: OnActionExecuting(), OnActionExecuted(), OnResultExecuting(), and OnResultExecuted(). For output caching, you want to capture the final rendered results. Therefore, you should override the last method to run: OnResultExecuting().

Here is inconsistency: If we need to override the LAST mentioned method, then it should be "OnResultExecuted". But in answer it is told "OnResultExecuting".

So the question is:

1. What is a CORRECT method to be overridden?
2. Which option should I choose on exam to get answer considered as correct? (Question is valid for case when "correct" answer is actually different from suggested by system.

Thanks.

P.S. I not sure if current question belongs to SO, but at least it is pretty close

Comment: I was just about to post the same question :)

Comment: It seems to me there are several pretty awful questions in the test program. I've been meaning to post a rant about it somewhere myself. This question certainly caught me out, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some time for me it made some sense: You should override 'OnResultExecuting' method in order to check if you have already result cached. If "yes" you will just get it from cache, if no, you will really execute functionality of "executing" part and then put it to cache.

Comment: Ah,ok that makes sense. But what about the statement in the Book's answer, that OnResultExecuting() is the last to execute? Even Still, with your approach, wouldn't the last one still being ...Executed()?

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to look at the [source for the built in OutputCacheAttribute](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63930#266508). The main guts of it is:

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) {
    if (filterContext == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }

    // we need to call ProcessRequest() since there's no other way to set the Page.Response intrinsic
    OutputCachedPage page = new OutputCachedPage(_cacheSettings);
    page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
}

private sealed class OutputCachedPage : Page {
    private OutputCacheParameters _cacheSettings;

    public OutputCachedPage(OutputCacheParameters cacheSettings) {
        // Tracing requires Page IDs to be unique.
        ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _cacheSettings = cacheSettings;
    }

    protected override void FrameworkInitialize() {
        // when you put the <%@ OutputCache %> directive on a page, the generated code calls InitOutputCache() from here
        base.FrameworkInitialize();
        InitOutputCache(_cacheSettings);
    }
}
```

So they have implemented it by overriding `OnResultExecuting`. I personally don't understand why you would wait that long... because the bulk of the time it takes for a request to process would be in the action method with all it's service, repository and whatever calls? No?

Maybe someone much smarter than me can explain.

Comment: Remember that this attribute could be applied to an action that modifies state on the server, it's conceivable that someone would return the same data despite the output being the same. Collecting information via get request for ads, images, and things like that are not unheard of. If you prevent the action from being called, that cannot happen. You don't want to do that at the framework level.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't agree with that approach. I, personally, would go with an override of OnActionExecuting and OnResultExecuted myself. It doesn't do much good to only override OnResultExecuted, since you've already executed the action method by the time the filter will be applied. You'd want to intercept the request before the action is executed and return the output cache in OnActionExecuting, and you'd want to capture the final result in OnResultExecuted.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that there is an `[OutputCache]` attribute built into MVC that handles output caching for you:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs.  For real development, this is likely a better approach than building a custom caching attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The convention says (in relation to event/event executing methods): progressive form = before executing the named action, and past tense = after it happened. So the correct answer should indeed be `OnResultExecuted`.

However, I would advise you to contact microsoft and ask for clarification.